# jQuery/JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'chosen' - Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, scripting, jquery-chosen

Working on an ASP.NET website. I am using a jQuery searchable dropdownlist. It is within an UpdatePanel.

I put several "alerts" in my code to aid in troubleshooting.

When the page first loads the effects are applied correctly to the dropdownlists. (Alerts 1, 2 & 3 appear fine.)

But, on the line after alert 3, I get an error. Here's the line...

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
```

The error is:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'chosen'

Why would it detect the 'chosen' method during the initial load (alerts 1 & 2), but not here? Here's the code....

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("3");
            // bind your jQuery events here initially
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
            alert("4");
          });
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        alert("5");
        // re-bind your jQuery events here
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
        $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
        alert("6");
      });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("1")
      $(".chzn-select").chosen();
      $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({
        allow_single_deselect: true
      });
      alert("2")
</script>
```

Comment: Check when the scripts are being imported, it is possible that because the first two are running before document ready that maybe something is loading in and overwriting something in chosen.jquery.js breaking the chosen() method.

Comment: Thanks @AldenBe What's the best way to check this? The first time "chosen()" is executed, between alerts 1 & 2 it works great. But then for the .ready function it errors out.

Comment: I would check by using chrome, press ctrl+shift+i for developer controls, then using the network tab. On page load, if any javascript loads after chosen.jquery.js try removing that and seeing if chosen() works again.

Comment: @AldenBe I think that's it! I copied the chosen.jquery.js reference to the end of the page, where there were other js references, and it woredk. But, a different jQuery control broke. So, looks like I have some conflicts going on.